# How to show $\big(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)\big)^\complement\cap U_\epsilon(B)\subseteq U_\epsilon\big( (U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\big)$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $A\subseteq B\subseteq M$ two closed sets and $0<\epsilon\leq\tilde{\epsilon}$ two real numbers. Further denote $$U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A):=\{z\in M: d(z,A)<\tilde{\epsilon}\}$$ the open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of the set $A$; analogous for the other sets and values. I want to show that $$\big(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)\big)^\complement\cap U_\epsilon(B)\subseteq U_\epsilon\big( (U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\big),$$ whereas $(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement$ denotes the complement of $U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)$.

By drawing a Venn diagram it is obvious that the statement holds, but I don't get it to write it down formally. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: It’s false as currently edited. Take $A=[0,1],B=0,1.01],\tilde\epsilon=\epsilon=0.02$; then $$U_\epsilon(B)\setminus U_{\tilde\epsilon}(A)=(-0.02,1.03)\setminus(-0.02,1.02)=[1.02,1.03)\;,$$ but $$U_\epsilon\big(B\setminus U_{\tilde\epsilon}(A)\big)=U_\epsilon\big([0,1.01]\setminus(-0.02,1.02)\big)=U_\epsilon(\varnothing)=\varnothing\;.$$

Comment: You are right! Sry I missed an assumption: $(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Is the statement true under this additional assumption?

Comment: I've asked the question again with the correct assumptions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638691/show-that-bigu-tilde-epsilona-big-complement-cap-u-epsilonb-subsete