# Show that $\big(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)\big)^\complement\cap U_\epsilon(B)\subseteq U_\epsilon\big( (U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\big)$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, $A\subseteq B\subseteq M$ two closed sets and $0<\epsilon\leq\tilde{\epsilon}$ two real numbers. Further denote $$U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A):=\{z\in M: d(z,A)<\tilde{\epsilon}\}$$ the open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of the set $A$; analogous for the other sets and values. Assume that $(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\neq\emptyset$ holds. I want to show that $$\big(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)\big)^\complement\cap U_\epsilon(B)\subseteq U_\epsilon\big( (U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement\cap B\big),$$ whereas $(U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A))^\complement$ denotes the complement of $U_\tilde{\epsilon}(A)$.

By drawing a Venn diagram it is obvious that the statement holds, but I don't get it to write it down formally. Has anyone an idea?

I've asked a similar question before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638245/how-to-show-bigu-tilde-epsilona-big-complement-cap-u-epsilonb-subse), but missed an essential assumption. That's why I'm asking it again with the correct requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a counterexample.

Let $d$ be the $\sup$ metric on $\Bbb R^2$:

$$d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\max\{|x_0-x_1|,|y_0-y_1|\}\;.$$

Let $A=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$, $B=[-3,3]\times[-3,1]$, and $\epsilon=\tilde\epsilon=2$. Finally, let $p=\left\langle 0,\frac52\right\rangle$; clearly

$$p\in U_2(B)\setminus U_2(A)=\big((-5,5)\times(-5,3)\big)\setminus\big((-2,2)\times(-2,2)\big)\;.$$

However,

$$\begin{align*}B\setminus U_2(A)&=\big([-3,-3]\times[-3,1]\big)\setminus\big((-2,2)\times(-2,2)\big)\\
&=\big([-3,-2]\times[-3,1]\big)\cup\big([-2,2]\times[-3,-2]\big)\cup\big([2,3]\times[-3,1]\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

whose nearest points to $p$ are $\langle -2,1\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$, and

$$d(p,\langle -2,1\rangle)=d(p,\langle 2,1\rangle)=2\;,$$

so $p\notin U_2\big(B\setminus U_2(A)\big)$.